# environment variables generated by at command

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, cron, at

I'm inspecting `/var/spool/cron/atjobs/a001cf01570e44` with `cat`, after running the `at` command from PHP using `exec()`.

It looks like `at` has prepended the script with lots of APACHE environment variables.

```
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=33 gid=33
# mail www-data 0
umask 22
APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2; export APACHE_RUN_DIR
APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid; export APACHE_PID_FILE
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin; export PATH
APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2; export APACHE_LOCK_DIR
LANG=C; export LANG
APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data; export APACHE_RUN_USER
APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data; export APACHE_RUN_GROUP
APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2; export APACHE_LOG_DIR
PWD=/home/jordanarseno/webroot/public_html/myapp; export PWD
cd /home/jordanarseno/webroot/public\_html/myapp || {
     echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
     exit 1
}
curl -k http://localhost/myapp/crons/this_action/3
```

The last line is the only real command I sent along with `at` via stdin. What is the purpose of these variables? Where is this procedure stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke the `at` command it copies the current environment so that's what you're seeing.

> The working directory, the environment (except for the variables TERM, DISPLAY and _)  and  the  umask are  retained  from the time of invocation.

You are running `at` in a php script via apache so what you are seeing in the script is the environment etc that apache is running in.

Comment: Thanks, what's the purpose though... What was the motivation for `at` to do this? And can I suppress them?... Or would it be wise not to do so? What is a command I could have handed to `exec()` that would be dependable on these variables? The reason I ask is I may have *many* scripts in the atjob directory and I'd like to keep them a small filesize.

Comment: @JordanArseno: The purpose is so that your command/script runs in the same environment as the account that added it to the queue. Cron runs jobs under a restricted environment - you wouldn't believe the number of questions we get here which are solved because the cron job environment is different from the OPs command line environment - at doesn't suffer from this problem. Your script above is 633 bytes - on any reasonably modern system you'd need billions of jobs to cause space problems surely?